# How to install pygame and livewires in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python3

This thread is not only about pygame but also about livewires. I followed the first answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034959/installing-python-modules-on-ubuntu) but when i write this command : `sudo pip install pygame`, I get an error saying:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pygame.
Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external pygame to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pygame
Storing debug log for failure in /home/cooldudeabhi/.pip/pip.log
```

How to fix them. Also, I am using **python 3.4**. Please help me to install both modules: Pygame as well as livewires.

Comment: If your using python3, you should be using `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal and type the following commands. It will install `pygame` on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial python3-pip libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
sudo pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

Regarding `livewires`, it seems that this package is for python2.x only as I got the following error when running `sudo pip3 install livewires`:

```
Running setup.py install for livewires
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/livewires/beginners.py", line 201
    raise ExBadParameters, "colour must be from Colour class"
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/livewires/boards.py", line 239
    if k <> l and k <> -l:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/livewires/games.py", line 110
    raise GamesError, "Cannot have more than on Screen object"
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Such errors are quite frequent when you want to run python2 code with a python3 interpreter.

---

**Update**: it seems possible to run 2to3 on the above files and successfully install `livewires`.

1. Download and extract [LiveWires-2.1.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/L/LiveWires/LiveWires-2.1.tar.gz#md5=738196e78637d5da16d2dc62996f45a4) from pypi.
2. `cd LiveWires-2.1`
3. `2to3 -w livewires/*`
4. `sudo python3 setup.py install`

Comment: I am using livewires with python 3.1 on my windows machine

Comment: @androidplusios.design: version 2.1 from pypi? please post your installation steps as a new answer if possible

Comment: For windows machine?

Comment: @androidplusios.design: Probably not ;). But I’m still curious about the python3.x compatibility.

Comment: Download the complete pack from here...instruction inside of the files.
http://bit.ly/1wmJ3mA

Comment: @androidplusios.design: Thanks for the link. The livewires version is 1.7 according to the games.py header.

Answer (score 2):

There is an Ubuntu package `python-pygame`. You can install it using the graphical application *Software* or on command line by

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

Comment: It's for Python2 only.