# Livewires module isn't working

Tags: python3

I'm learning Python and I followed this topic [How to install pygame and livewires in ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594781/how-to-install-pygame-and-livewires-in-ubuntu-14-04)
to install Livewires which are required for the primitive game I'm learning to build.
However when I launch the program I get this: `ImportError: No module named livewires`

What's the problem here ? pygame and livewires should be installed successfully.

I'm importing the module as follows: `from livewires import games`

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SuperWires
where reader learns about new version of "livewires" which is called "superwires" and is compatible with all versions of Python incl. Python3.